# C# generic defs class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to find elegant solution for defs class in C# Example:

Instead of:

```
class Class1
{
    public static readonly string length = "length_Class1";
    public static readonly string height = "height_Class1";
    public static readonly string width = "width_Class1";
}

class Class2
{
    public static readonly string length = "length_Class2";
    public static readonly string height = "height_Class2";
    public static readonly string width = "width_Class2";
}
```

Create template class. I thought of the following solution but it looks not so elegant:

```
internal abstract class AClass
{

}
internal class Class1 : AClass
{

}
internal class Class2 : AClass
{

}

class Class1<T> where T : AClass
{
    public static readonly string length = "length_" + typeof(T).Name;
    public static readonly string height = "height_" + typeof(T).Name;
    public static readonly string width = "width_" + typeof(T).Name;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have a lot of parameter names that I get/set from external data source, I would like to have two Instances of Defs for that. Length , Weight, Height are only for Illustration, there are a lot more.

EDIT:

I chose Generics because I think that there is a way to make the concatination in compile time (like in c++). Is it possible to do that?

Could you help me with more elegant solution?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is there any particular reason that You need the string literal names to refer to a particular class?  Perhaps if you elaborated on what you're hoping to achieve, we can find a better way!

Comment: what is it that you are trying to *achieve* here? that is probably important... what are these values going to *mean*?

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to not include the class name in a variable name. Why do you want to do so?

Comment: How do you plan on using Length, Width, and Height?  Why have you chosen to use static?

Comment: I have a lot of parameter names that I get/set from external data source, I would like to have two Instances of Defs for that.

Comment: And I do not want to concat the names in the runtime.

Comment: (I removed my answer because of downvoting, sorry I couldn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't actually need the properties to be `static`, or the class to be generic. So, you can do something like:

```
class ParameterNames
{
    public string Length { get; private set; }
    public string Height { get; private set; }
    public string Width { get; private set; }

    public ParameterNames(string className)
    {
        Length = "length_" + className;
        Height = "height_" + className;
        Width = "width_" + className;
    }
}
```

Although you might want to refactor your code, so that the code that accesses the external resource doesn't need to deal with those parameter names at all:

```
abstract class ExternalResource
{
    private readonly string m_className;

    protected ExternalResource(string classname)
    {
        m_className = className;
    }

    protected object GetParameterValue(string name)
    {
        string fullName = name + '_' + m_className;

        // actually access the resource using fullName
    }
}

public class SpecificParameters : ExternalResource
{
     public SpecificParameters(string className)
         : base(className)
     { }

     public int Length { get { return (int)GetParameterValue("length"); } }

     …
}
```

Doing this wouldn't avoid concatenating strings repeatedly, but I'm not sure why you want to avoid that, doing that should be pretty fast.

Comment: It is good solution, but there are a lot of parameters and the are called frequently , I chose generics because i think that there is the way to make the concatination in compile time?

Comment: .Net generics are not C++ temples, they are not computed at compile time. Besides, you should measure that the concatenations actually do matter to you. And if you know they do, computing them once when program starts should be still fine, and that's what my first solution does. (And you could modify the second one to do the same.)